# Using ReactJs with Cloud Firestore V9, I have an issue with rendering to the dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning how to use Cloud Firestore from Firebase combined with React JS.
For starters here what my Cloud Firestore data looks like...
[image]
I was reading the documentation for V9 but I still had issues.
[Link to -> Firebase docs : Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

I actually even copied and pasted what I read and it worked! **BUT!! Only for a brief moment.** I wasn't sure if I changed the code by accident. Since for some reason it wasn't rendering to the dom, I console.log a few items and it showed something was happening. I was able to see data values in the console! But still nothing was being rendered. Here's my code... and screenshots of my console.

```
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
apiKey: "Hidden",
authDomain: "Hidden",
projectId: "Hidden",


 });
  const db = getFirestore();

  const [dataFB, set_dataFB] = useState([]);

  async function getSomethingTEST() {
    let items = [];
    const q = await query(collection(db, "WNA-Pasteur-Items"));
    await onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        items.push(doc); // <-- Here I also tried doc.data().nameENG
      });             // And was able to see the specific values in the console. 
      console.log("What is inside: ", items.join(", "));
    });
    set_dataFB(items);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getSomethingTEST();
  }, []);
```

The first console.log with only items from doc , I got this... [image]
The second console.log with doc.data().nameENG , I got this...
[image]

Then with my JSX code looked liked this.

```
    <p>please work</p>
    {dataFB.map((e) => (
      <div key={e.id}>
        <h3>{e.nameENG}</h3>
      </div>
    ))}
```

Which rendered this...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the document data instead of document snapshot:

```
items.push(doc.data())
```

Then stringing before rendering:

```
console.log("What is inside: ", JSON.stringify(items.join(", ")))
```